# ESP32 Cam send picture to cloud AWS

Tags: esp32, aws

I am trying to figure out how to convert an image to base64 on the ESP32 Cam board so I could then send it to AWS s3 bucket. Could someone please give me some insight?

[image: camera pins used]

Comment: What have you already tried? Also some information about what camera you are using and how it's attached to the ESP32 would probably be useful.

Comment: I have tried using SPIFFS to upload an image to a webpage. Beyond that I have done a lot of research that tells me it may not even be possible. I added an image of how the camera is connected.

Comment: What does the GPIO pinout have to do with "`how to convert an image to base64 on the ESP32 Cam board`"? Don't you have the image as a file or data structure?

Comment: The image is a jpg on the sd card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem we have here is: *ESP32 may not have enough RAM to do it.*

There are a few examples on the web on how to save data collected from the ESP32-CAM to a microSD card. If you are familiar with that, you can now take a look on the **base64.h** library for the ESP32 arduino enviroment. If not, there is a very comprehensive tutorial by Rui Santos on YouTube, which you can find on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eot6COwCPF0) link.

Base64.h is a library for ESP32 (core) that implements the base64 conversions as simple as *decode* and *encode*. You can take a look on the source on [github](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/cores/esp32/base64.cpp).

I never used the ESP32-CAM, but the result you want to achieve seems very simple to me. Have a look on those links and give it a try.

Comment: I talked with Rui on his forum. He said something about using encode function. But I cant find the comment. TBH it is a bit over my head how to implement that github library